# Epson TM-T88V-i print only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, epson

I've a problem with an Epson TM-T88V-i printer, I can print the first time but after I receive always a `EPOS2_ERR_CONNECT` error.

I use the example in the [SDK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=52&pid=2773) and it has this problem.

This is the code:

```
int result = EPOS2_SUCCESS;

if (self.printer == nil) {
    return NO;
}

result = [self.printer connect:@"TCP:192.168.1.15" timeout:EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT];
if (result != EPOS2_SUCCESS) {
    return NO;
}

result = [self.printer beginTransaction];
if (result != EPOS2_SUCCESS) {
    [self.printer disconnect];
    return NO;
}
```

After the first time it goes in the if after  the connect method with the `EPOS2_ERR_CONNECT`

I must restart the printer to reprint something.

Comment: Under what conditions do you disconnect?  If you try and connect when you are already connected you will get an error.

Comment: After print. When I try to connect it is disconnected.

Comment: Is the issue fixed?

Comment: @Bharath, yes. Read the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem months ago...

For the TM-T88V-i printers you must connect with another syntax:
use `<connection type>:<identifier>[<device ID>]` instead of `<connection type>:<identifier>`

So your code is something like this:

```
result = [self.printer connect:@"TCP:192.168.1.15[local_printer]" timeout:EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT];
```

N.B. local_printer is the default identifier.